# How to split a String disregarding spaces?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split this String: `"send#hi how are you"` into

1. `send`
2. `hi how are you`

and then split `"hi how are you"` into

1. `hi`
2. `how`
3. `are`
4. `you`

My attempt:

```
text[0] = "send#hi how are you";
String[] one = text[0].split("#");
String[] two = text[0].split("#")[1].split("\\s#");
```

When splitting `"send#hi how are you"`, it only gives me "send" and "hi"...

How can I change my code so it works?

Comment: Not `"\\s+"` but just `"\\s"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that should work, assuming that you don't want the word before the pound symbol:

```
String x = "send#hi how are you";
x = x.substring(x.indexOf("#")+1, x.length());
String[] splitUp = x.split(" ");
```

If you do want both what's before and what's after the pound:

```
String x = "send#hi how are you";
String before = x.substring(0, x.charAt("#"));
String after = x.substring(x.charAt("#")+1, x.length());
String[] splitUp = after.split(" ");
```

And here's another way to do the second:

```
String x = "send#hi how are you";
String[] pieces = x.split("#");
//at this point pieces[0] will be the word before the pound and pieces[1] what is after
String[] after = pieces[1].split(" ");
```

A final note - splitting on `" "` is one way to do it, but splitting on `"\\s"` is basically the same thing using regex, which may be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the text being split on (in this case `"#"`) is *consumed* by the split - ie it's not retained in any of the resulting strings.

The smallest edit to get you going is to change:

```
String[] two = text[0].split("#")[1].split("\\s#");
```

to:

```
String[] two = text[0].split("#")[1].split("\\s");
//                                             ^--- remove the #
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String str = "send#hi how are you";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^#]+)#(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
  String first = m.group(1);
  String[] second = m.group(2).split("\\s+");

  System.out.println(first);
  System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(second));
}
```

or if you want the simplest way:

```
String str = "send#hi how are you";

String[] parts = str.split("#", 2);
String first = parts[0];
String[] second = parts[1].split("\\s+");

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(second));
```